# What program is represented by this flowchart? What loop should we implement in the program? What would be the output with n = 10?

Tags: python

[image]

What would be the algorithm and code for this flowchart?

```
n = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
count = 0
sum =0
#if count>n then break otherwise stay in the loop:
count = count+2
sum = sum+2
while count<=n:
    count=count+2
    sum=sum+2
print(sum)
```

Comment: the flowchart is a graphical representation of the algorithm.  You code is almost correct but you need to change the location of your while statement

Comment: Should I write like this:

n = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
count = 0
sum =0

while count<=n:
    count=count+2
    sum=sum+2
print(sum)

Comment: Yes, the while statement should represent the point where the flowchart loops back.